# How to Open a link on button click From a Default Activity other than Main Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to assign a link to a button that is in another activity other than main activity. I tried using Intent and Uri.parse but the application kept crashing. On the other hand, if I used Intent and Uri.pase on a button in Main Activity it was working fine. Can anybody help me, please?

Here's the MainAcitivity and on "info" button press it takes me to a new activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
 Button info;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);
    info.setOnClickListener(this);

    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new 
SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.info) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(".Options");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
}
```

The code for the second activity goes as follows:

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);`
}


public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

}

I want that a link opens when I click on the button from the Options Activity.

Comment: Could you please add your code here?

Comment: I have added the code with the post.

Comment: You're talking about link but I don't see any link in your code. Moreover, your Intent is badly created. See : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)

Comment: Other remark in your `Options` activity : you can't retrieve component before setting the content view

Comment: I will add the code to attach the link to the button. But I need to know, how to exactly do it so that it works i.e. the button in the Options activity opens up a link on button click. And you are correct with the remark thing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a `Url` from `MainActivity` to `OtherActivity` so that the user will be redirect to it when it will taps on `OtherActivity.Button` ?

If yes, use `Intent` to pass the Url

```
class OtherActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    companion object {
        private const val EXTRA_KEY_URL = "OTHER_DETAIL.EXTRA_KEY_URL"

        fun launch(launcher: Activity, url: String) {
            val intent = Intent(launcher, OtherActivity::class.java)
                    .apply {
                        putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_URL, url)
                    }
            launcher.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private lateinit var url: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity)

        url = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_URL")

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            // use url here
        }
    }
}
```

How to call it from your `MainActivity`

```
val uri = /* your Uri */
val str = uri.toString()
OtherActivity.launch(this, str)
```

**Edit according to your need, in Java**

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String EXTRA_KEY_URL = "OTHER_DETAIL.EXTRA_KEY_URL";

    Button button;
    String url;

    public static void start(final Activity launcher, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(launcher, Options.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_URL, url)
        launcher.startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_URL")

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        /* use url*/
    }
}
```

Then, in `MainActivity`

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.info) {
        // get your url
        String url = ""; //TODO
        OtherActivity.launch(this, url);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get the answer from algorithm that you sent. Could you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: I have added the code for my program for better clarity.

Comment: My code is made in Kotlin, but easily convertible in Java. I gave you an example about how passing an argument from one activity to another. Is that not what you wanted ?

Comment: That is what I want, but I couldn't convert your code to java code as I require.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope it will better help you better